# JMeter - I want to log/display error responses only in CLI mode

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin, jmeter-logging

I could see that in GUI mode there is an option to log/Display only errors in View Results tree listener.

[Please refer to the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJTGe.png)

How can i do the same thing on CLI mode, I want lo log/display errors only, please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to disable logging of failed samplers, the options are in:

Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) at global level (the same level as all your Samplers live or higher, see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) for more details) and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
if (prev.isSuccessful()) {
    prev.setIgnore()
}
```

these lines will prevent successful samplers from being caught by listeners and from being stored in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles?src=contextnavpagetreemode)

Comment: Hi thank you, I have tried this, but after adding this  JSR223 PostProcessor  at the global level, it is listing only the successful samplers, i want to print error/failed samplers

Comment: Apologies, made a typo, remove `!` from the code